# .Net SQL Client Provider

Tags: .net, sql, client

Have come across a situation where a stored procedure is executed in Query Analyser in less than a second. But when the same stored procedure is executed using the .NET SQL Client Provider, it is taking 61 seconds.

Therefore in order to troubleshoot this issue we went to SQL Profiler we find the request comes to SQL Server less then a second but execution completed after 60 seconds.

Can anybody explain why we have such a deviation?

Query is quite simple:

```
SELECT distinct 
    p1.productID, p1.description  
FROM  
    Details V   
INNER JOIN 
    Product P ON V.ProductID = P.ProductID     
INNER JOIN 
    product p1 ON p1.productID = p.parentID      
WHERE 
    V.MarketID = '1159' 
    AND V.FinancialYear = '1213' 
    AND V.LEPeriodID = '75' 
    AND p1.parentID = 100024 
    AND p1.statusID = 1  
ORDER BY 
    description
```

Comment: I have seen this kind of problem before if the Query Analyzer and the application used different settings regarding NULL handling (ANSI_NULL) or sorting (collation). The query in QA was quick because the settings matched those used to create the indexes, and it was slow in the application because the indexes could not be used due to different settings.

Comment: Where do we add this setting in Application